# gzip compression to http responseWriter

Tags: json, rest, http, go, gzip

I'm new to Go. But am playing with a REST Api. I cant get the same behavior out of json.Marshal as json.Encoder in two functions i have

I wanted to use this function to gzip my responses:

```
func gzipFast(a *[]byte) []byte {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    gz := gzip.NewWriter(&b)
    defer gz.Close()
    if _, err := gz.Write(*a); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return b.Bytes()
}
```

But this function returns this:

```
curl http://localhost:8081/compressedget --compressed --verbose
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8081 (#0)
> GET /compressedget HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8081
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Wed, 24 Aug 2016 00:59:38 GMT
< Content-Length: 30
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Here is the go function:

```
func CompressedGet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps  httprouter.Params) {

    box := Box{Width: 10, Height: 20, Color: "gree", Open: false}
    box.ars = make([]int, 100)
    for i := range box.ars {
        box.ars[i] = i
    }
    //fmt.Println(r.Header.Get("Content-Encoding"))

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Encoding", "gzip")
    b, _ := json.Marshal(box)
    //fmt.Println(len(b))
    //fmt.Println(len(gzipFast(&b)))

    fmt.Fprint(w, gzipFast(&b))
    //fmt.Println(len(gzipSlow(b)))
    //gz := gzip.NewWriter(w)
    //defer gz.Close()
    //json.NewEncoder(gz).Encode(box)
    r.Body.Close()

}
```

But when i uncomment:

```
//gz := gzip.NewWriter(w)
//defer gz.Close()
//json.NewEncoder(gz).Encode(box)
```

it works fine.

Comment: Maybe because the 3 lines are unnecessary? The gzipFast function is already doing the gzipping of the json encoded box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flush or close your gzip writer before accessing the underlying bytes, e.g.

```
func gzipFast(a *[]byte) []byte {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    gz := gzip.NewWriter(&b)
    if _, err := gz.Write(*a); err != nil {
        gz.Close()
        panic(err)
    }
    gz.Close()
    return b.Bytes()
}
```

Otherwise what's been buffer in the gzip writer, but not yet written out to the final stream isn't getting collected up.

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid gzip-ing `[]byte` manually. You can easily use already existing writers from standard library. Additionally, take a look on `compress/flate` which I think should be use instead of gzip.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "encoding/json"
    "compress/gzip"
    "log"
)

type Box struct {
    Width int `json:"width"`
}

func writeJsonResponseCompressed(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    box := &Box{Width: 10}

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Encoding", "gzip")

    body, err := json.Marshal(box)
    if err != nil {
        // Your error handling
        return
    }

    writer, err := gzip.NewWriterLevel(w, gzip.BestCompression)
    if err != nil {
        // Your error handling
        return
    }

    defer writer.Close()

    writer.Write(body)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/compressedget", writeJsonResponseCompressed)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))
}
```

Comment: I agree, this was really just a test for me to learn some things. If this api were production app then your solution is best.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the use of `fmt.Fprint(w, gzipFast(&b))`.

If you look to the definition of gzipFast it returns a `[]byte`. You are putting this slice into the print function, which is "printing" everything into `w`.

If you look at the definition of the io.Writer:

```
type Writer interface {
        Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) }
```

You see that the writer can handle `[]byte` as input.

Instead of `fmt.Fprint(w, gzipFast(&b))` you should use `w.Write(gzipFast(&b))`. Then you don't need to uncomment:

```
//gz := gzip.NewWriter(w)
//defer gz.Close()
//json.NewEncoder(gz).Encode(box)
```

Everything as a small example, which shows what is happening in your code:

https://play.golang.org/p/6rzqLWTGiI